# bigint id changed back to int during table rename

Tags: postgresql

I hit the int limit on a large table I use.

The table is in single user mode and has no FK constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_bigint (LIKE my_table INCLUDING ALL);
ALTER TABLE my_table_bigint ALTER id DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE my_table_bigint alter column id set data type bigint;
CREATE SEQUENCE my_table_bigint_id_seq;
INSERT INTO my_table_bigint SELECT * FROM my_table;
ALTER TABLE my_table_bigint ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval('my_table_bigint_id_seq');
ALTER SEQUENCE my_table_bigint_id_seq OWNED BY my_table_bigint.id;
SELECT setval('my_table_bigint_id_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM my_table_bigint), true);
```

At this point I tested that I could insert new rows without any problems. Success, I thought.

I went about renaming the tables.

```
alter table my_table rename my_table_old
alter table my_table_bigint rename my_table
ALTER INDEX post_comments_pkey RENAME TO post_comments_old_pkey
ALTER INDEX post_comments_pkey_bigint RENAME TO post_comments_pkey
```

Now, when I checked the schema.... the table ID type had changed BACK to `integer`, instead of `bigint`.

Copying took about 3 days - so I am really, really hoping that I don't need to do this again. This is postgres10 on RDS.

---

EDIT

I'm going to take care of this problem like this:

Create a new table - call it `my_table_bigint2`.
Do this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_bigint2 (LIKE my_table INCLUDING ALL);
ALTER TABLE my_table_bigint2 ALTER id DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE my_table_bigint2 alter column id set data type bigint;
CREATE SEQUENCE my_table_bigint2_id_seq;
ALTER TABLE my_table_bigint2 ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval('my_table_bigint2_id_seq');
ALTER SEQUENCE my_table_bigint2_id_seq OWNED BY my_table_bigint2.id;
```

And start populating that table with the new data. (This is fine given the usecase.)

In the meantime, I'm going to run

```
 ALTER TABLE post_comments alter column id set data type bigint;
```

And finally, once that's done, I'm going to

```
INSERT INTO my_table SELECT * FROM my_table_bigint2;
```

My follow-up question - is this allowed? Will this create some interaction between the sequences? Should I use a new sequence?

Comment: Did you `COMMIT` after the `RENAME` of the tables? Are you looking at the correct table? A `RENAME` will not change data types, so something else is happening here.

Comment: I did not commit after renaming the table - (I'm using postico to interact with the db) - it appeared everything was updated correctly.

Comment: So everything is correct now? Otherwise the issue could be that this: `alter table my_table rename my_table_old` should be `alter table my_table rename TO my_table_old`. The form you show in your question fails with a syntax error.

Comment: It appeared to be correct until I tried inserting, then it failed and I realized the type was still int. Also, very strange, I had no syntax error on my part?

Comment: Use `psql` and look at tables there.

Comment: Same thing in psql

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the same database? I cannot replicate here(on community edition Postgres) so I suspect is a RDS issue.

Comment: 100% sure. The only thing I can think of is... could it have to do with renaming the primary keys? Or the insert *?

Comment: No. Data types don't change in a table definition unless you specifically do so with an `ALTER TABLE ... SET DATA TYPE`.